# How to change profile picture in stackexchange data explorer

Tags: discussion, support, profile-picture

I'm trying to change **[my stackexchange data explorer profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18981/zakaria-acharki)** but when I click on **Change Picture** it always redirect me to **http://gravatar.com/** (I've already an account but I but I can not change it):

[image]

Is it necessary to pass with gravatar to change your profile picture? is there another way to change it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to set this up yourself.  I had the same issue trying to link my accounts and get my profile picture to sync.  I contacted support and the exchange was as follows.

Me:

> Can you please associate https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18041/jon-doe18042 to my account https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver
>   For some reason it never linked at the first time and I cannot delete that sede account.
>
> I have tried submitting this as a merge request but every time I do that it get an we have encountered an error message.

SO:

> Hello,
>
> Our Data Explorer is not able to associate to other accounts on the network, because it does not run on the same code base and is not connected to the rest of the network in any way. If you'd like your usual display name and other information to be displayed, you'll need to edit your profile there independently.
>
> Regards,
>
> Stack Overflow Team

Me:

> Thank you for that. I was able to change my name so that is resolved. The only issue I have now is trying to change my picture just brings me to gravatar.com and I see no way to change my picture.

SO:

> Hello,
>
> Unfortunately, the only way to update your profile picture on Data Explorer is through Gravatar, so you'll need an account with them to change the photo. When the "change picture" link takes you to gravatar.com, you can log in or create an account there to get started.
>
> I'm sorry for the inconvenience - it stems from Data Explorer being a totally separate codebase from the rest of Stack Exchange.
>
> Regards,
>
> Stack Overflow Team

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, its ok now it take a while before synchronization..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Glad to hear it is working now.